# Find the worst case running time of this algorithm for checking if a number is divisible by 3

Tags: c, algorithm, time, division, analysis

I wrote this algorithm for checking a number's divisibility by 3. It works by first checking if the input N is a single digit number. If N is not a single digit number, the sum of its digits is calculated and assigned to N. The outer while loop iterates until the number of digits n is equal to 1. Then the program checks if the final value of N is equal to 0, 3, 6 or 9, in which case N is divisible by 3.
e.g. When N=5432157 and n=7, then N=5+4+3+2+1+5+7=27 and n=2, then N=2+7=9 and n=1. Thus, the outer while loop iterates 3 times.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    main(){
        int N,n=0,rN,sum=0;
        printf("Enter the number: ");
        scanf("%d",&N);
        rN=N;
        while(n!=1){
            n=0;
            sum=0;
            while(N>0){
                sum+=N%10;
                N/=10;
                n++;
            }
            N=sum;
        }
        if(N==0||N==3||N==6||N==9){
            printf("\n%d is divisible by 3.",rN);
        }
        else{
            printf("\n%d is not divisible by 3.",rN);
        }
    }
```

For the worst case analysis, I have assumed that all the digits of N are equal to 9. What I have observed is that for number of digits n less than 11, the outer while loop iterates a maximum of 3 times. For n greater than or equal to 11 but less than 10^11, the loop iterates a maximum of 4 times. I tried out a few cases for n greater than or equal to 10^11, and saw that outer loop iterates 5 times. I have not been able to find a general formula for this case. Also, for the inner while loop, which iterates n(number of digits in current value of N) times for each iteration of the outer while loop, how does n decrease with each iteration of the outer while loop?

Comment: you could just use: `if( !(number %3) )`  then number is evenly divisible by 3

Answer (score 5):

If you observe carefully, each of your (outer) iteration takes `log(N_current)` steps. With each step your number also becomes `log(N)` (or `9*log(N)` to be precise).

The outer iterations will go on till the `N_current` has 1 digit.

So your total complexity will be -

```
log(N) + log(log(N)) + log(log(log(N))) + ... + 1 ;     (1)
```

The number of iterations would be [log*N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm).

Now, I do not know how to reduce (1) but if you over approximate and consider each step to be `log(N)`, you can write the complexity as

**`O(log(N) * log*(N))`**
<sub>(Mind the capital O)</sub>